# pyvot: can I run Excel VBA macros from python script?

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, com, vba

Say I have loaded `Report WW26blueprint_with_chart_330.xlsm`  in the `report` object with the following code (the `print.range` is used here to test that the workbook is loaded):

```
import xl
report = xl.Workbook("Report WW26blueprint_with_chart_330.xlsm")
print report
print(report.range("A1:E50").get())
```

From the [pyvot documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/Pyvot/tutorial.html#interop) I get that:

> Pyvot is written on top of Excel’s COM API. You can always get the
>   underlying COM object and make COM calls yourself

My Excel file has the following macros:

```
Macro1 
Масго2 
Macro7
```

Can I run any of the above macros directly from the python script using python/pyvot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did it for me:

```
report.xlWorkbook.Application.Run('Macro1')
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't manage to do it with `pyvot` but can be done using `pywin32` as following:

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Users\florinescu_eduard\Downloads\\Report WW26blueprint_with_chart_330.xlsm",ReadOnly=1)
xl.Application.Run("Macro1")
xl.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Application.Quit()
xl=0
```

Answer (score -1):

It's very important to make sure `xl.Application.Quit()` while you are debug. Other than you might get confused.