# Run Excel from Python, Run Macro WITH Credentials

Tags: python, excel, odbc, connection-string

I have a block of code that I have used in the past to touch an excel file, run a macro already saved in the workbook, save and close.  For example:

```
import win32com.client
import os
import os.path

file = 'myworkbook.xlsm'
path = 'C:/PATH/'
macro = 'mymacro'

filename = os.path.join(path, file)
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
wkbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
runMacro = wkbk.Name + '!' + macro
xlApp.Run(runMacro)
wkbk.Save()
wkbk.Close(1)
xlApp.Quit()
xlApp = None
```

However, I would now like to use this on a macro that refreshes a data connection, and thus prompts for the password for the SQL database in question.  When I try to run this, without worrying about the credentials, I get this error:

> com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, u'Microsoft Office
>   Excel', u"Cannot run the macro 'MYMACRO'. The
>   macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be
>   disabled.", u'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Office\Office12\1033\XLMAIN11.CHM', 0, -2146827284), None)

Is there a way to make this work---i.e. to pass the required credentials from python to excel so that the macro can run?

Comment: why wouldnt you just port the macro to python ... and not deal with excel at all?

Comment: Can you elaborate? The whole point is to update this particular excel file, which has conditional formatting, is distributed to several parties, etcetera.

Comment: I dunno I hate having excel in my workflow and go to lengths to avoid it ... anyway have you looked at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/19638459/541038 (setting the macro permissions in excel, which you may need to do and somehow save so that they always run macros ...  are you sure the macro exists?

Comment: I'll take a look---and I hear you about excel, but in this case there's no way around.

Comment: The other SO answer addresses a different issue, sadly.