# Is there any way I can call Excel VBA function through Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Do anybody know a method to call  Excel VBA function in Python.

In my case, I would like my program which is programmed in Python produce an output in Excel by calling a function which is created in Visual Basic.

Is there any method on doing that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In order to do this you will need to use pywin32, and use the excel com interface.

Please review the documentation for the [Excel Com Interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7.aspx):

Please note this has been asked before [Running an Excel Macro via Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python)

The code below is a slight modification of the original.

```
import os
import win32com.client

#Launch Excel and Open Wrkbook
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")  
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\Full Location\To\excelsheet.xlsm") #opens workbook in readonly mode. 

#Run Macro
xl.Application.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!modulename.macroname") 

#Save Document and Quit.
xl.Application.Save()
xl.Application.Quit() 

#Cleanup the com reference. 
del xl
```

Good Luck.