# python excelApplication.Run

Tags: python, vba, excel, pywin32

i want to open some excel file on python script 
and apply macro files

what i want to know is that 
i get macro file with data path and using it

Is there any solution for my questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `win32com` to open an excel file. if the macro is already present in the excel file(It has to be macro enabled excel file), then run the following code

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
excel_app_object = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel_app_object.Run("excelsheet.xlsm!modulename.macroname")
```

If its not a macro enabled excel file, i suggest you to convert the macro to python and run it through Dispatched COM Object
You can check [This SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python) for more