# Run macro from one workbook to another using python

Tags: python, vba

I have a python code which reads in a file (file1), makes adjustments and then exports it back out to my Documents. I have written a macro called Macro1 and it is stored in file2.

In Python, how can I call Macro1 from file2 to run on file1?

This is the VBA for Macro1 that I have so far that is stored in file2:

```
Sub ColumnWidths()
    Dim Wsht As Worksheet
    For Each Wsht In Worksheets
        With Wsht.UsedRange
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
         End With
    Next Wsht
End Sub
```

So I just need to somehow reference file1 in the code and then have it run through python.

Comment: The file1 have the macro ?

Comment: Add some minimal code of what you did so far, to bring things into better context

Comment: Does the vba code in file2 reference file1 in the code?  Otherwise vba defaults to the "active" file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running an Excel macro via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python)