# Using python to call a excel macro

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm trying to write a python code that will run a macro in a excel workbook.  I know the file name and name of the vba macro.  I don't need to read any information into the python file I simple need to perform this function.

I ultimately want to run this python code periodically and I want it to call the same VBA function multiple times in a day.

```
import openpyxl


excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('python test.xlsm')
print type(excel_document)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this Code on Stackoverflow. Maybe it helps you.

Resource:
[Running an Excel macro via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python)

````
import win32com.client

if os.path.exists("excelsheet.xlsm"):
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath("C:\Users\{Username}\Desktop\test.xlsm"), ReadOnly=0)
    wb.Sheets('Sheet1').Select()
    xl.Application.Run("test.xlsm!Module1.macroname")
##    xl.Application.Save() # if you want to save then uncomment this line and change delete the ", ReadOnly=1" part from the open function.
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl```
````

Comment: Can you go into more detail on the syntax perhaps.  If I saved the excel file to my desktop and the name is test.xlsm and the sheet I want to perform a macro in is 'Sheet1' how would that look in the syntax?

Comment: you have to set the filename instead of "excelsheet.xlsm" like `C:\Users\{Username}\Desktop\test.xlsm`. What do you mean by, the Macro is in Sheet1? Isn't it located in a Module?

Comment: @AnP Is everything clear? Or do you have any further problems?