# Calling an Excel function from Python and importing the output with unknown dimension resulted, once the function has completed running

Tags: asynchronous, win32com, xlwings

I am trying to use Bloomberg Excel built in functions (BCurve, BView,...) in Python. I am currently using xlwings and i have tried using some of the posts that explain how to run macros from Python using win32com, but I have not seen how to capture the range of cells that are output of the function and avoiding importing the results before the function has completed running.

[Running an Excel macro via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python)

Comment: Are you trying to call BCurve etc purely in Python without having to use them as formula in the spreadsheet? is that your question?

Comment: Hi Felix, that would be ideal but not sure if there is a way to do that. What i thought it could be possible is to call excel from python to run the function and import the results once all cells have been populated. No sure if xlwings support this.