# Python write a macros in .xls file on linux

Tags: python, excel, vba, xls

I generate .xls file and use xlwt, xlrd and xlutils, but when i use the copy function from xlutils, every macro is missing in the new file.

I need to write my own macros to the .xls file, but I already looked for a solution on google and i've only found libraries for windows.

Is there any way to create macros in python for .xls files?

Please help me.

Comment: Maybe worth adding a simple example to explain how you create macros in python for xls files in windows. I was looking for something similar (running excel vba macro through python on linux) but it seems to be impossible from the findings I had

Comment: If you want create macros in windows you need win32com.client. Look here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python