# Follow up question on running a vba macro using python

Tags: python, excel, vba

hi I am using the answer provided here
[Running an Excel macro via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python)

codes:

```
filename = "NewVba.xlsm"

if os.path.exists(filename):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(filename), ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run(filename+"!"+ "PK_new_try")
##    xl.Application.Save() # if you want to save then uncomment this line and change delete the ", ReadOnly=1" part from the open function.
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl
```

which runs fine, the only issue is when I put the file in some other folder and provide the entire path as shown below 
`filename = "C:\Users\kamathp\Downloads\ExcelVBAs\NewVba.xlsm"`

I get an error :

```
File "<input>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

whence got clue how do I fix this??

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your error says it all. You need to escape the [escape character](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html) `\`
Meaning your path needs to look like this: `"C:\\Users\\kamathp\\Downloads\\ExcelVBAs\\NewVba.xlsm"`

Comment: thanks @Nacorid, still getting this error - result = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(*(dispid, LCID, wFlags, retType, argTypes) + args)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', "Cannot run the macro 'C:\\Users\\kamathp\\Downloads\\ExcelVBAs\\NewVba.xlsm!PK_new_try'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.", 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)

Comment: how do I enable macros from my python codes? (although I think they are enabled)

Comment: @PrasKam This sounds like an XY problem. Check if your VBA code compiles, the error you are getting is a generic error, if it doesn't you should ask a new question.