# How do you reference a Macro Enabled Excel workbook and run VBA code in Python?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have built an optimization model in Excel which I am trying to loop through for several observations and store the optimal outputs for each. I have a dataset that I am trying to read into python and then have a loop put in the input values to the Excel sheet, run solver/VBA code, and then return the output for each observation.

Below is the dataset that I have with my input values, followed by the current code that I am trying to use. I current have this code below, which I got from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/19743828/11046221, as it appears to have gotten me the furthest. However I tried to find how to reference the "Module" name and was not able to get it to work, so I saw further in the post to reference the sheet name, which did not work either, both resulting in the error message:

**"Cannot run the macro 'P:/optimization_model_reference.xlsm!Excel_Model.run_solver_v2'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."**

```
obs var1    var2    var3
0   27  80  100 125
1   35  56  93  128
2   42  48  89  108
3   53  70  91  109
4   59  73  86  89



if os.path.exists("P:/optimization_model_reference.xlsm"):
    xl=win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath('P:/optimization_model_reference.xlsm'), ReadOnly=1)
    xl.Application.Run("P:/optimization_model_reference.xlsm!Excel_Model.run_solver_v2")  #This I have in the format ("file_name!sheet_name.macro_name")
    xl.Application.Quit()
    del xl
```

Comment: Avoid the absolute reference of path in `Run`: See this [duplicate post solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19743828/1422451).

Comment: @Parfait that was the post I referenced, however I was not able to get it to work. The error message that I am getting is a result of that answer.

Comment: Once again, did you remove the absolute path (i.e., remove `P:/`)? See link as no full path to workbook is used in `Run`.

Comment: What does "it didn't work* mean? Same error? Is *Excel_Model* your own defined standard module (i.e., not behind any worksheet or workbook)? And *run_solver_v2* name of the `Sub` macro residing inside standard module?