# Trying to open an excel using a python code

Tags: python, excel, win32com

HI am trying to open an excel using python codes on windows (python version is 3.6.10)

I used codes from the link 
[Running an Excel macro via Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python)

```
import win32com.client as wincl

excel_macro = wincl.DispatchEx("Excel.application")
excel_path = os.path.expanduser("Valuation.xlsm")
workbook = excel_macro.Workbooks.Open(Filename = excel_path, ReadOnly =1)
```

but the excel doesn't open at all, and I don't get any errors either!

if however I run the rest of the code to run the vba macro it does work fine (but the file still doesn't open)

```
excel_macro.Application.Run("Macro1")
excel_macro.Application.Quit()
del excel_macro
```

Question is, how do I simply open the excel file using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the Excel application visible. Without setting this [Application.Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.visible) property to `True`, the application runs in background and be sure not to call `Quit`. And of course with any API integration, be sure to wrap in `try/except`:

```
import win32com.client as wincl

excel_path = os.path.expanduser("Valuation.xlsm")

try:
    excel_app = wincl.DispatchEx("Excel.application")
    workbook = excel_app.Workbooks.Open(Filename = excel_path, ReadOnly =1)

    # RUN PROCESSING
    excel_app.Run("Macro1")

    # LAUNCH EXCEL VISIBLY TO SCREEN
    excel_app.Visible = True

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:
    workbook = None; excel_app = None
    del workbook; del excel_app
```

Comment: perfect! that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

import os
os.system("start EXCEL.EXE dummyfile.xlsx")

Answer (score 0):

Really simple way to open excel file saving the structure is using pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
```