# Trouble Running Excel Macro from Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I am trying to run an Excel Macro from Python - which I've never done before - using the following method from [this site](https://pythoninoffice.com/how-to-run-excel-vba-macro-from-python/):

[Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ynba.png)

However, the "wb = ..." line doesn't register. Python isn't recognizing ".Workbooks" as a property of the "xl" Excel Application variable.

I can open the Excel workbook using a simple openpyxl line, but then the subsequent "xl.Application.Run..." line doesn't register. Maybe I'm missing another module that I need to import besides just win32com.client? Something that the above website assumed I would already have?

Any insights appreciated.

Comment: Try this from [here](https://pythonexcels.com/python/2009/10/05/python-excel-mini-cookbook)? `xl = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')`

Comment: If you haven't already, read this thread, too. There are some samples from within the past couple years. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616205/running-an-excel-macro-via-python

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I tried the "gencache.EnsureDispatch" function, but ".Application.Run" remains unrecognized by the interpreter. Looking through that more recent thread, there is one person there ("William Tong") who seems to have had the same problem as me. He never really resolved the problem, but rather implemented a different workaround solution. I'll try his workaround to see if it works, although I'm still interested in the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I still haven't gotten the original issue resolved, but Denton Thomas' thread suggestion did point me to another way to accomplish the same thing using the library "xlwings". I didn't use it initially, because it's supposedly designed to work with older versions of Excel, so I wanted to work with a new more comprehensive library. Nevertheless, it worked just as I expected, running a simple macro. I'm now curious if I can find a way to perform this same code, but without having to open the Excel spreadsheet every time...

```
import xlwings as excel

wb = excel.Book(XXX) #Insert filepath/filename for "XXX".
my_macro = wb.macro("Main")
my_macro()
wb.save()
wb.close()
```