# Python script to run vba Error msg

Tags: vba, python-3.x

I've posted the same question here
[pyvot: can I run Excel VBA macros from python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17446807/pyvot-can-i-run-excel-vba-macros-from-python-script#51623435)

I'm new to Python, so I do alot of searching.
Trying to Run a VBA project using snippets of Python code
Have encountered this error message, Win 7 based error I think.
Error message from PyScriptor reads as:

> com_error:(-2147352567,'Exception occured',(0,"Microsoft \excel',
>   Excel cannot access 'MYFOLDERNAME,,  The document may be read-only or
>   encrypted,", 'xlmain11.chm.,0,-2146827284),none)

---

Sorry about the forum errors, thought it was being helpfull, as I'm not taking the credit for this actual peiece of code.

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\MYFOLDERNAME",ReadOnly=0)
xl.Application.Run("py_counter_test")
xl.Workbooks(1).Close(SaveChanges=1)
xl.Application.Quit()
xl=0
```

This the error I get, believe it's Win 7 issue.
I know I have not encrypted the folder, it is simply a "New Folder" in C:\

com_error:(-2147352567,'Exception occured',(0,"Microsoft \excel', Excel cannot access 'MYFOLDERNAME,, The document may be read-only or encrypted,", 'xlmain11.chm.,0,-2146827284),none)

Thanks

Comment: The link you posted improperly uses the answer space to post something other than an answer. You should go back and delete it. You should also [edit] this post to include the code you're using, so we can see what you're doing and perhaps figure out the issue. We can't debug code we can't see. Spend a minute or two reading [ask] and [mcve], and then edit to include the relevant portions of your code. It also helps if you use complete sentences when asking.

Comment: Is the document read-only or encrypted? The error message seems pretty clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the error,( over-sight ) left out the workbook name.
Amended  code error.

```
import win32com.client
xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="C:\MYFOLDERNAME\PY-COUNTER.xlsm",ReadOnly=0)

xl.Application.Run("Macro1")
```